# How to correctly disable ngbRadioGroup?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am currently using [ng-bootstrap radio buttons](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples), predominantly with Reactive Forms, but also within custom controls which implement `ControlValueAccessor`.

I am trying to figure out what would be the correct way of disabling the entire `ngbRadioGroup`.

I can manage to disable it with Reactive Forms by calling `.disable()`. That works fine, however:

**Q1: What is the correct way of disabling the `ngbRadioGroup` using the template driven approach?**

**Q2: Is it possible to disable it using `Renderer2` or is there a bug here?** e.g. I am currently doing the below, it would be great if ngbRadioGroup could work with this approach:

```
@ViewChildren('control') private controls: QueryList<ElementRef>;

setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
   this.controls.forEach(control => {
       this.renderer.setProperty(control.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
   });
}
```

Here is a StackBlitz showing what I have investigated so far:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vp1ozl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewChild to access NgbRadioGroup instance

```
@ViewChild(NgbRadioGroup,{static:true}) ngbRadioRef:NgbRadioGroup;
```

Then you can set the disable property true or false dynamically

```
disable(){
    this.ngbRadioRef.disabled = true;
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwyi2j)

Comment: This works, thanks! I think it would be good if it worked from the standard 'disabled' property on the element, as then I wouldn't have to treat the ngbRadioGroup differently to other controls, but it works just fine.

Comment: Since ngbRadioGroup is a wrapper for button element,It's does have a element access you can check the source code here:https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/buttons/radio.ts#L20